# Automake use absolute path for sources when configured from another folder

Tags: c++, macros, automake

There is a project. With `myprog.cpp`, `Makefile.am` and `configure.ac` files in the root.

myprog.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << __FILE__ << std::endl;
}
```

1) From terminal I can use `autoreconf -if && ./configure && make && myprog`
Then it prints out `myprog.cpp`

2) From terminal I can use `autoreconf -if && mkdir temp && cd temp && ../configure && make && myprog`

Then instead of `myprog.cpp` or at least `../myprog.cpp`, I get full absolute path: `/my/log/absolute/path/to/folder/myprog.cpp`

==================

It is known, that `__FILE__` macro is just printing out the path which was provided to gcc during the compilation.

I want to configure from another folder. But I want `__FILE__` macro to contain just filename, as if I configure from the `ROOT` folder.

Can I achieve this somehow?

I want exactly `__FILE__` macro contain just name of the file. I don't want to create another macro (like here in this example: `#define __FILENAME__ (strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : __FILE__)`).

Comment: The issue is probably with the Makefile output from automake. I don't use it this way myself, but you could check this by `diff` ing the two generated `Makefile`. The pragmatic answer may be to run sed on the Makefile to replace the long paths with the shorter paths?

Comment: Having `strrchr` look for the last `/` would not really help anyway for files in subdirs. You would probably have to add a `-DTOP_BUILDDIR?'"@top_builddir@"'` to the `foo_CPPFLAGS` and then have a macro which prints only the part of `__FILE__` which comes after `TOP_BUILDDIR`. Worst case, you would need some `realpath` calls on both `@top_builddir@` and on `__FILE__`.